# Dialogflow CX: How to get the entire transcript between the user and the bot at any point in the given session?

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-cx

I'm building a bot using Dialogflow CX and I would like to get the entire transcript, particularly the text messages that the user responded when a particular intent is triggered.

I'm using a Node.js server to communicate with the bot from a React application.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to Pass data to Dialogflow cx bot platform using webhook fulfillment and store it in the format you want.

Another way is to connect with any third-party tools that support Dialogflow integrations. There's a chat transcript feature that will send the entire transcript to the email that you want.

Please refer to this [doc](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/settings#chat-transcript) for more details and the setup.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand that correctly, you try to get the conversation between bot and user.
For that you should use a Webhook-Integration, that sends a request message to your Webhook. In your Webhook you can feel free to save the json request or edit it.
For example in python:

```
import json

def cx_debug_json(request):

  request_json = request.get_json()
  
  with open("conversation", 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(request_json, json_file)
```

Your file than should have a json format with different specifications. If you just want the specific text strings, you have to edit the request_json. For example to delete specific paramaters:

```
if "fulfillmentResponse" in request_json.keys():
    response_json["fulfillment_response"] = request_json["fulfillmentResponse"]
if "pageInfo" in request_json.keys():
    response_json["page_info"] = request_json["pageInfo"]
if "payload" in request_json.keys():
    response_json["payload"] = request_json["payload"]
if "sessionInfo" in request_json.keys():
    response_json["session_info"] = request_json["sessionInfo"]
    if "parameters" in response_json["session_info"].keys():
        if target_parameter in response_json["session_info"]["parameters"].keys():
            response_json["session_info"]["parameters"][target_parameter] = None
```

Now you need to figure out the key names of the text strings (simple debug the incoming request from the webhook) and then editing or extract them as you like.